# A function which is both $o(\log^* n)$ and $\omega(1)$

Tags: asymptotics

I've been trying to find a function $T(n)$ whose asymptotic rate of growth satisfies both of the following conditions:

1. $T(n)= o(\log^*n)$
2. $T(n)= \omega(1)$

But I can't think of a function with this rate of growth.

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Take $ T(n) = (\log^*n)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(n) = o(g(n))$, then the function $h(n) = \sqrt{f(n) g(n)}$ satisfies $h(n) = o(g(n))$ and $h(n) = \omega(f(n))$.

Answer (score 2):

A notable function that is not upper bounded by any constant but grows slower than $\log^* n$ is $\alpha(n)$, the [inverse of the Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse).

This function appears naturally in the analysis of Union-Find with path compression.